# iframe no se ve en la página Google Sites

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, google-sites

El problema que tengo es que quiero lograr que en una página web de Google Sites (la cual acepta `iframe`) se pueda ver otra pagina.
El tema es que he probado con páginas como Google y si ha funcionado, pero al colocar la página que quiero: http://webcurso.uc.cl/portal, no aparece nada.

El código que puse es:

```
 <iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="http://webcurso.uc.cl/portal">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que la página que quieres incluir en el `iframe` esté bloqueando eso. Hay varias formas de hacerlo ya sea usando JavaScript o mediante encabezados `X-IFRAME-OPTIONS`.